# Tkinter update label images every x seconds

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple Tkinter app for an image slide show.

I'm using the `.after(100, rotate_image)`update the image associated with a label every 100ms.
`updater()` is defined in order to run this as an infinity loop while the window is open.

For some reason, the image updates only once. It doesn't cycle to items 2 or beyond in the list.
My intention is to rotate images in `1->2->3->1->2->3....`

Similarly a button is associated to the same function `rotate_image`
The button works fine and rotates through the list of images.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import  Image, ImageTk 

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Image scroll")
window.geometry("800x600")
window.minsize(300, 300)   


#load image, resize & place text
wx= 150
hx = 150

images =[ 'beach.jpg', 'DSC325.jpg','DSC323.jpg']
val=0

def load_img(img_name):
    global photo1   # alternative fix for photoimage garbage colelction issue
    img = Image.open(img_name)
    img = img.resize((wx,hx), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo1=  ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    return photo1

def rotate_image(event=None):
    global val
    # simple Rotation function to loop images  `1->2->3->1->2->3.`
    if val== len(images)-1:
        val=0   
    else:
        val +=1  # select next 
    img2= load_img(images[val])
    img_panel.configure(image=img2)
    img_panel.image = img2

def updater():
    count=1
    while count<=100:
        window.after(100, rotate_image)
        count+=1

#define main layout frames
frm_LEFT_outer = tk.Frame(master=window, width = 600,bg= '#beb7e2', relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
frm_LEFT = tk.Frame(master=frm_LEFT_outer, bg= '#beb7e2', relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
frm_LEFT_outer.pack(side =tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True ) 
frm_LEFT.pack(expand=True, )

img_panel = tk.Label(master=frm_LEFT, image=load_img(images[val]))
img_panel.pack(expand=True)

btn_next = ttk.Button(master=frm_LEFT, text="NEXT", width=8, command=rotate_image)
btn_next.pack(expand=False)

updater()  # auto loop through images while the window is open

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You called `.after()` a hundred times in a row, so 0.1 seconds later you get a hundred calls to `rotate_image()` in quick succession.  You need to call `.after()` once at a time, then call it again in the delayed function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `after()` in wrong way.  Change `updater()` as below:

```
def updater():
    rotate_image()
    window.after(100, updater)
```

Comment: Thanks. It fixed the problem. So this approach is to call the function recursively.  Is there an alternative method to pass the rotate_image function handle properly into the `after()` instead.

Comment: If you want to call `rotate_image()` periodically, you can use `after(100, rotate_image)` but you need to call `after(100, rotate_image)` at the end of `rotate_image()` as well.  However, since `rotate_image()` is also called by a button, using the above logic is not appropriate.